# Code coverage with AspectJ and Lombok

Tags: code-coverage, aspectj, jacoco, lombok

We are using Lombok and other annotations (using AspectJ) a lot in our code and that is impacting the branch coverage. Is there any way to exclude this auto-generated code in code coverage calculations. We are using Jacoco for code coverage.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm a Clover developer at Atlassian.

Did you try other code coverage tools? For instance, the Atlassian Clover is based on the source code instrumentation (contrary to JaCoCo or Cobertura which rely on bytecode instrumenation). Thanks to this different approach, Clover is more "transparent" to any bytecode-manipulating tools. So using Clover + Lombok + AspectJ should be fine in your case.